# Understanding boxes at the primitive level

Tags: tex-core, boxes

I'm learning **plain** TeX as a nerdy *hobby*. My current project involves trying to divide the page into unequal columns. I only want to use boxes and glue, with *no external* dependencies, e.g. `eplain`. Before diving the page I wanted to learn how to frame a box, to assist my learning through visualisation. My attempt to visualise the writing area i.e. `vsize` and `hsize` produced an overfull `hbox`. My minimal working example is:

```tex
\hrule
\hbox to \hsize{
  \vrule
  \vbox to \vsize{
    \vfill
    \hfill
  }
  \vrule
}
\hrule
\bye
```

The output was:

```
Overfull \hbox (5.24442pt too wide) detected at line 9
Overfull \vbox (10.4pt too high)
```

Can someone please explain to me what is causing the boxes to overflow given that I am only using glue. My hunch is that I am placing my box inside an existing "default" box, which it is overflowing.

I am using `ubuntu 22.04` and `pdftex --version` outputs the following:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

Thanks.

Comment: The following MWE compiled without problems: `\vrule\vbox to \vsize{  \hrule\hbox to 0.9\hsize{\hfil}\vfil\hrule}\vrule\bye
`. I think I must not be understanding vertical and horizontal mode correctly. I'm also still confused about needing the `0.9` multiplier for `hsize`.

Comment: I realised part of the problem was a lack of `noindent`. However, the `hbox` is still overfull by `0.4pt`.

Comment: The question isn't really about plain, more about TeX's core box model - I've edited lightly to reflect that

Comment: Off topic:  repeating `\vfill` doesn't do anything useful unless there's something in the middle.

Comment: Thanks @JosephWright.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `\hbox to\hsize` includes space from the the end of line 2, `\vrule` (width 0.4pt), `\vbox` (width `\hsize` because of `\hfill` inside it), space from the end of line 7, `\vrule` (width 0.4pt). The sum of this material has its width greater than `\hsize` by 5.24442pt.

The height of this box is equal to height of `\vbox` inside it. The first `\hrule` is inserted to the first baseline (its distance is `\topskip`=10pt for the upper boundary of the `\box255` propagated to the output routine. Then there is the box of `\vsize` height and then the second `\hrule` (0.4pt). So the `\box255` has its height: 10pt+`\vsize`+0.4pt. So, the output routine reports `\vbox` 10.4pt too high.

Comment: Thanks @wipet. To clarify the rules were occupying the extra space?

Comment: If a line doesn't end by a control sequence (lines 2, 4, 7 and 9 in your example) then the token processor (with default settings) generates space here. Spaces at lines 4 and 7 are ignored by the main processor because they are in vertical mode. Spaces at lines 2 and 7 are in horizontal mode and they are not ignored.

Comment: Thanks @wipet. That makes sense now,